# How to determine if there is anything to read in a websocket buffer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket

Is there any way of knowing if there is data in the buffer before performing a `ws.recv()` using `websocket-client`?

I'm trying to avoid threading as it's for a test unit.

The problem I'm having is that at a determined moment I'll have 3 connections opened, but only one of them is going to have data in its buffer, so I can't just use something like `ws1.recv() ws2.recv()` and `ws3.recv()` because the program will keep waiting for data in an empty buffer.

Comment: could you not just use `settimeout` to let it give up if there is no data?

Comment: Doesn't python support the `select` system call?

Comment: @JoranBeasley it wasn't in the documentation (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/), but analyzing the lib files I found it's possible to pass a `timeout` to the ´connect´ method, which uses `socket.settimeout` under the hood. For my needs this will suffice, so **thank you!** but I can't accept that as an answer because the question is about *how to determine if there is data to read* and not about *how to prevent a system halt due to no data to read*